# Trigger multiple delegates based on event data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm kind of new in Swift. I'm working with [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) trying to implement a chat. I've created a delegate protocol which defines some functions:

```
@objc protocol EvDelegate {
    optional func didAuth(with user: User)
    optional func didAuth(with error: Error)

    optional func didReceive(message: Message) 
    optional func didReceive(error: Error)

}
```

I've also created an `Event enum`:

```
enum Event: String {
    case auth = "auth"
    case message = "message"

    var allEvents: [Event] {
        return [.auth, .message]
    }     
}
```

I have implemented an `EventManager` which registers multiple delegates and listens for events:

```
class EvManager {

    var delegates: [String: EvDelegate]
    func add(delegate: EvDelegate, withKey key) {
        delegates[key] = delegate
    }

    func listen() {
        // listen for Socket.IO events
        for event in Event.allEvents {
            socket.on(event.rawValue) { data, ack in
            // trigger the associated delegate **[HOW?]**
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data json that I get from the server through `Socket.IO` has this structure:

```
{ status: true, responseData: { ... } }
```

or

```
{ status: false, error: "Some kind of error message" }
```

How should I proceed in triggering the delegates based on the data that I get from the server? I know that I should grab each element from the `delegates` array and call the one of the delegate functions, but I'm having trouble figuring out which one of the functions should I call and how to create its params. As you can see, in the `EvDelegate` protocol, each delegate function has an object as a parameter, which should be created automatically based on the response status and response data. Also, as you can imagine, the delegate protocol will have much more functions in it.

Please guide me.

---

Update:

This is how i imagine the `listen` method would look

```
    func listen() {
        // listen for Socket.IO events
        for event in Event.allEvents {
            socket.on(event.rawValue) { data, ack in
                switch event {
                    case .auth: 
                        if let user = SomeParser.fetchUser(data: data) {
                            for listener in listeners {
                                lister.didAuth?(with: user)                                                
                            }
                        } else {
                            let error = SomeParser.findError(data: data)
                            for listener in listeners {
                                listener.didAuth?(with: error)                                                
                            }
                        }            
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this the best way to do it? I find it kind of cumbersome.

Comment: Have you considered using `NotificationCenter` instead of an array of delegates?

Comment: @alexburtnik thanks for your suggestion. `NotificationCenter` could be a solution also, but the problem doesn't lies there. I'm looking for an elegant solution to call the correct method and create & pass the param object based on the event and the response data.

Comment: You should read again on how to use delegate...you haven't even created delegate variable on your `EvManager ` yet, nor parsed the data json, also you can just combine success and failed function to one method

Comment: @EricBrimer So what's the problem of "creating and passing the param object" through the notification's `userInfo`? Delegation is not the best option if there are multiple objects to be notified about some event

Comment: I'm using @Tj3n it's an array of delegates.

Comment: delegate is made for 1-1 relationship, if you have more than 1 subcribed on your `EvManager`, use `NSNotificationCenter` instead, im not even sure why you want to make array of delegates

Comment: @Tj3n i've updated the question... Thanks a lot guys for trying to help me.

Comment: As i said, since you have multiple listener, use `NSNotificationCenter` to send a notification is a better way, if you still want to do this way, just simply loop through your `delegates` array, get the delegate out with key, then just call `delegate.didAuth`

Comment: @Tj3n is what i did in the updated question ok?

Comment: I think it would work, but you have to know that it would create problem is that some of the delegate might become nil if the parent got released, you should check it before calling

Comment: @Tj3n i set the delegate methods as optionals and called them like this `listener.auth?(user: User)` i just forgot about it. My issue is that this solution is not very scalable. I would automate it and call the delegate methods programatically. Isn't there a better way?